# The best method of numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

how to compute numerically the integral

```
NIntegrate[6 x/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]
```

to give a value which is approximately  equal to 891.441

Comment: Your answer is wrong. This integral does not converge. Try `Integrate[6 x/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}]` and you'll get an error message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relavant mathematics.

Comment: How it can be computed without issuing the message? @Roman

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this by finding the integral from 0 to something a little less than 1:

```
f[eps_] = Integrate[6 x/(1 - x), {x, 0, eps}, Assumptions -> 0 < eps < 1]
-6 (eps + Log[1 - eps])
```

Now you can see explicitly that as eps -> 1, the integral diverges to -Infinity.

```
Limit[f[eps], eps -> Infinity]
-\[Infinity]
```

Answer (score 0):

The integral does not exist:

```
Limit[Integrate[6 x/(1 - x), x], x -> 1]

(* \[Infinity] *)

out = Quiet@
   Table[{wp, 
     NIntegrate[6 x/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> 1, 
      WorkingPrecision -> wp]}, {wp, 10, 500, 5}];

ListPlot[out, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Working Precisin", "NIntegrate Result"}]
```

[image]